# Gradle copy task expand with properties derived at execution time

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In gradle, I am currently doing something like this:

```
task generateConfiguration(type: Copy) {
   into "$buildDir/generatedConfiguration" 
   from "src/main/config-templates" 
   expand(loadConfig())
}
```

`loadConfig()` is using Groovy `ConfigSlurper` to load Groovy based config and it return a `Map` for the "expand" method to consume.

This approach works find with one caveat.

the `loadConfig()` is invoked during configuration phase.

If I would like to defer the `loadConfig()` process until execution phase, I cannot do it with this approach. `expand()` method doesn't accept closure.

Any good sugguestion so that I can defer the loadConfig into execution phase?

I have been looking for a simple solution for awhile already with no luck.
Right now, I have only two possible routes:
1) implement a map object which will defer the `loadConfig()` operation until the map is accessed by the template engine
2) reimplement the copy task so that it can take a closure.

I'm trying to look for a simpler options though..

Comment: Did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
task generateConfiguration {
   doLast {
      copy {
         into "$buildDir/generatedConfiguration" 
         from "src/main/config-templates" 
         expand(loadConfig())
      }
   }    
}
```

This way the parameters should be expanded at execution phase.